# Rails: typeahead.js dropdown returns duplicates or objects that were deleted

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, typeahead.js, typeahead

I have installed `typeahead.js` on my rails app but when I start typing a word inside the input field the dropdown returns duplicates or objects that were deleted along with the correct word as well.

This it the setup I have:

inside the controller:

```
def autocomplete
 render json: Item.search(params[:search], {
    fields: ["title"],
    match: :word_start,
    limit: 10,
    load: false,
    misspellings: {below: 5}
 }).map(&:title).uniq
end
```

and inside the view:

```
<script>
var items = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: '/items/autocomplete?search=%SEARCH',
        wildcard: '%SEARCH'
    }
});


$('#search')
    .typeahead(null, {source: items})
    .on('typeahead:selected', function(e){
        $("#search-form").submit();
    }).focus();
</script>
```

Any idea how can I fix this?

**Update 1**

If I do this inside the rails console it returns an empty array, which is correct because currently I don't have items inside the database. But If type inside the input field old items that were delete appear in the dropdown:

```
2.4.0 :026 > Item.all.map(&:title).uniq
  Item Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items"
=> []
```

Comment: What is the response from your API? Check the network tab of your browser. Does the response have duplicate/deleted entries?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ash , actually no it doesn't have any duplicate/deleted entries!

Comment: Cool. I just wanted to rule out that it was a server side issue.